# How to use npm packages in an angular 2 app?

Tags: angular, npm

I want to send some UDP packets from my angular 2 app.
While searching for a solution I found some npm packages that look like they could do the job.

I thought I could just install and use this packages in angular but it did not work. Some research reavled some howtos but they look very diferent so that I am totally confused.

Can I use every npm package with angular? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not every package; there are limits. Browserify implements replacements for many of Node's built-in APIs, but not everything is possible in the browser.

This is discussed in the [compatibility section](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#compatibility) of the documentation.

If a package relies upon an built-in API that is not browser-compatible - or relies upon native code - it won't work. And, as far as I am aware, sending UDP packets is not going to be possible.

Comment: thanks, I read that UDP would not be possible but I thought that there might be a way with this packages. Do you know if it is possible to send TCP packets?

Comment: I very much doubt it. XHR, WebSockets and WebRTC are the only options of which I am aware, but I'm no expert in browser-based networking stuff.